# Electron close and min button do not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, native

**Hi
I'm a beginner in js and electron js 
I'm using Windows 10 pro and here is my main.js:**

```
    const electron = require("electron");
    const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

    app.on("ready", () => {
      let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        frame: false,
        nodeIntegration: false,
        title: "Myapp",
      });
      win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
      win.on("close", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        win.destroy();
      });
    });

    exports.openWindow = (filename) => {
      let subwin = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1400, height: 900 });
      subwin.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/` + filename + `.html`);
    };
    app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
      if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
      }
    });
```

**and my index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Electron tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <header>
        <div class="close-btn" id="close-btn">x</div>
        <div class="min-btn" id="min-btn">-</div>
      </header>
      <section>
        <div id="text">
          <h1>Hello Electron</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script src="Home.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**and my Home.js:**

```
const remote = require("electron").remote;
const main = remote.require("./index.js");

document.getElementById("min-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
  window.minimize();
});

/*document.getElementById("max-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
  if (!window.isMaximized()) {
    window.maximize();
  } else {
    window.unmaximize();
  }
});*/

document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
  window.close();
});
```

** I could not find out how to make the close, min, max buttons work
I did some tries and none of them worked
This didn't work in Linux as Well
Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeelp!
I'm losing my mind :)**

Answer (score 0):

```
nodeIntegration: true
```

Change false to true, so that you can use Node API at your renderer.
Now you are facing this error sine you are disabling Node API on your renderer.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

In your case this error comes from `const remote = require("electron").remote;`